# How to get the price of variable product using variation ID?

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, price, product-variations

I have variation ID of a product. Is there any way to get the price of particular variation ID.

I tried with the below code.

```
$variation_id = 12312;
$price = get_post_meta($variation_id, '_regular_price', true);
```

Answer (score 10):

> You code will not display the correct price if you have set a sale
>   price for that product so you should use `_price` key for that.

Here is the code which will workout for you.

```
$variation_id = '12312';
$price = get_post_meta($variation_id, '_price', true);
```

OR

```
$variation_id = '12312';
$variable_product = wc_get_product($variation_id);
//$regular_price = $variable_product->get_regular_price();
//$sale_price = $variable_product->get_sale_price();
$price = $variable_product->get_price();
```

Please Note: *You can use anyone of the above given method but I'll recommend you to use the last one, because if WooCommerce change the `metakey` then the first code snippet will not work but the 2nd one will work.*

Hope this helps!

Comment: Wouldn't changing the last line of your code to `$price = $variable_product->get_price();` be even more future-proof?

Answer (score 0):

Did you try:

```
$variation_id = '12312';

$price = get_post_meta($variation_id, '_regular_price', true);
```

Comment: This worked for me at that time, don't know why anybody would downvote this comment.

Comment: It would be better if they provided a reason the answer was unhelpful. My best guess, given this was 2017, is that there was only code and no explanation.